# Echo out SQL result to create a timetable

Tags: php, html, sql, echo

I am having problems printing out a timetable using the results from a SQL statement and some HTML layout with PHP.

I have the times of the classes along the top of the page. 
I am trying to put the days of the week along the side of the page and then check if the result of the SQL statement (containing a module) should be printed in the specific day and time.

```
//Print out the top of the array to display the times
echo "<div><table class='table table-bordered'><thead><tr><th></th><th>9-10</th><th>10-11</th><th>11-12</th><th>12-13</th><th>13-14</th><th>14-15</th><th>15-16</th><th>16-17</th></tr></thead><tbody>'";

//Now loop through the result of the SQL statement that contains the modules associated with the selected course
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
    for($d = 1; $d < 6; $d++){
        $printday = $days[$d];
        echo "$printday";

        for($t = 9; $t < 17; $t++) {
            if($row['Day'] == $d && $row['Time'] == $t){ //fix this area so that it moves along
                echo "<td>" . $row['ModuleName'] . "<br/>\n " .$row['Location'] . "</td>";
            } //if
            else {
                echo "<td></td>";
            } //else
        } //for 2

        echo "</tr>";
    } //for 1
} //while
```

The problem is that I am printing out Monday-Friday 3 times as there are 3 $row results. Any idea how I could get this to work.

Comment: `echo "<td></td>";` should be  `echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";` -- as to the rest, I don't get what you're trying to do.

Comment: theproblem is not his HTML.. just remove that for block and use the stuff inside of it.

Comment: @Pamblam I bet those numbers represent a 9-5 workday

Comment: @Pamblam 9-5 working day along the top. monday-friday down the side. As I have 3 results it is posting the first row in the correct place, but it is then printing out the rest of the days. It then moves on to the second result and does this. Therefore rather than having 5 days with 3 modules displayed. I have Monday-Friday displayed 3 times (15 altogether) and 3 modules

Answer (score 0):

Your looping through your data in the wrong spot, you first need to put that in an array so you can loop through it for each day/time.

```
//Print out the top of the array to display the times
echo "<div><table class='table table-bordered'><thead><tr><th>Day</th><th>9-10</th><th>10-11</th><th>11-12</th><th>12-13</th><th>13-14</th><th>14-15</th><th>15-16</th><th>16-17</th></tr></thead><tbody>'";

//Now loop through the result of the SQL statement that contains the modules associated with the selected course
$courses = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
    $courses[] = $row;
} //while

for($d = 1; $d < 6; $d++){
    $printday = $days[$d];
    echo "<tr><td>" . $printday . "</td>";

    for($t = 9; $t < 17; $t++) {

        unset($course_row);

        foreach($courses as $course){
            if($course['Day'] == $d && $course['Time'] == $t){ //fix this area so that it moves along
                $course_row .= $course['ModuleName'] . "<br/>\n " .$course['Location'] . "<br/>\n<br/>\n";
            } //if
        }

        if(isset($course_row)){
            echo "<td>" . $course_row . "</td>";
        } else {
            echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
        } //else
    } //for 2

    echo "</tr>";
} //for 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it is nearly working exactly how i would want it to. I have one error which I cant quite understand: .....Notice: Undefined variable: course_row in C:\xampp\htdocs\judeProject\502\generateTT.php on line 70.... do you see where the problem is? thanks

Comment: its because I am using `.=` here `$course_row .= $course['ModuleName']`, and I am doing that so your schedule will show as many classes scheduled for that time as there are ... what if 4 are scheduled for that time.  If that won't happen just change it to `=`

Comment: Your answer was perfect, but in my case there is no classes scheduled at the same time. I will keep this in mind for the future. Thanks for the help, greatly appreciated

Comment: @JudeHargan please accept the answer as correct! thanks!